# Javascript/jQuery cancel a function in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that on hover, it shows the image next to the list item. That works fine. However, I need to have it so that when the user clicks the link, the image stays there. As of right now when the user clicks the link the hover function still prevails and the image will only show if the link is being hovered over.

```js
$('[href]').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').prev('li').removeClass('hidden');
}, function() {
    $(this).closest('li').prev('li').addClass('hidden');
});

$('[href]').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    $(this).closest('li').prev('li').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
ul, li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="hidden"><img src="https://placehold.it/30x30" /></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happening because hover overwrites click. I create this solution so when click the link the image remains visible:

```js
var clickHref = false;

$('[href]').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('li').prev('li').removeClass('hidden');
}, function() {
  if (!clickHref)
    $(this).closest('li').prev('li').addClass('hidden');
});

$('[href]').click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  $(this).closest('li').prev('li').removeClass('hidden');
  clickHref = !clickHref;
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="hidden">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/30x30" />
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the off method fit your needs:

```
$('[href]').click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  $(this).off("mouseenter mouseleave").closest('li').prev('li').removeClass('hidden');
});
```